# Splitting or Substr one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql, clob

I have a table  `poll` and i have 600 rows in `poll`. The type is `CLOB`. Some rows contain 12000 or 15000 character in `data` column. When it contain 12200 character i need make multi column like that:

```
data1        data2        data3        data4
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
first 4000   second 4000  third 4000   last 200
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: type is **Clob** sir

Comment: What do you want in the new columns? Just numbers, or the actual content of the CLOB, by 4000 character chunks?

Comment: actual content of the CLOB  data1(first 4000) data2(second 4000)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dmbs_lob.substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349):

```
select
    dbms_lob.substr(data, 4000,     1) data1,
    dbms_lob.substr(data, 4000,  4001) data2,
    dbms_lob.substr(data, 4000,  8001) data3,
    dbms_lob.substr(data, 4000, 12001) data4
from mytable
```

Comment: Length and substr support clob too